# Why does PHP stop recognizing $_GET variables?

Tags: php, get

Something very odd has happened with a site/server that I do not have hosting access to.

I have a script that has been running for over 2 years. It has recognized `$_GET` vars from the URL address with no problems.

Now all of a sudden the script does not process any `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` vars. I have made no changes to my PHP scripts since I launched them 2-3 years ago.

Does anyone know if there are recent server updates or PHP updates that can cause a working script to stop recognizing `$_GET` vars?

**WordPress Plug-in script:**

```
function email_this($data)
{
    global $post;
    if(isset($_GET['id']))//if it is a form
    { // 2014-05-03 SCRIPT DOES NOT FALL THROUGH HERE
        email_send(htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']));    
    }
    else//if the button should show
    { // 2014-05-03 SCRIPT FALLS THROUGH HERE
        $data_and_emailthis = $data; // 2011-03-23: split original statement into 2 statements
        $data_and_emailthis .= '<!--'; // 2011-03-23: added this to comment out ability to email articles from non-specified pages
        $data_and_emailthis .= '<br/><p><a href="/email/?id='.get_the_ID().'" rel="nofollow" title="Email this post to your friend" style="font-weight: bold;"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/emailthis/email.gif" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" alt="Email this post"> Email this post</a></p>'; // 2011-03-23: split original statement into 2 statements
        $data_and_emailthis .= '-->'; // 2011-03-23: added this to comment out ability to email articles from non-specified pages
    }

  //return
  return $data_and_emailthis;
  }

add_filter('the_content', 'email_this');
```

**URL:**

```
http://mydomain.com/email/?id=1506
```

**.htaccess file**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 41.207.163.6
```

Comment: Hi, again :) Are you sure, that your html link contains `id=SOME_ID`?

Comment: Very sure...I amended my OQ

Comment: and this script and site has not changed in a couple years. The only thing that could have changed would be something the datacenter has done with the server or with PHP

Comment: Have you changed / added any rewrite rules in a `.htaccess` file for example?

Comment: looks like some wordpress related issue. May be `/email` url processed by other script, or something else like this

Comment: No, I have not made any site changes in a couple years @jeroen

Comment: but why does the script fall through to the else? the url has the id as part of the query string

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` file? Perhaps the query string is not passed, although I don't know why that would change all of a sudden.

Comment: .htaccess file posted

Comment: ok, but I changed my script from testing _GET['id'] to if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/email/') !== false)//if it is a form and it is working. So I am moving on

Comment: Problem solved. The hosting provider blocked our email form and it violated their security policy. Yet, they neglected to inform us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how it was before, but to pass the query string, you need to modify:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

That way the query string gets appended after the url has been rewritten to `index.php`.

Comment: ok, but I changed my script from testing `_GET['id']` to `if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/email/') !== false)//if it is a form` and it is working. SO I am moving on

Comment: Even without htaccess rules, if you have `var_dump($_GET)` in your index.php and you try to open `index.php/blabla/?id=1` it will find the `id` key

Comment: @H.Ferrence How is it working? I would assume you'd need the ID in your mail function.

Comment: @RoyalBg The OP is opening `/email/?id=1506` and that gets rewritten to `index.php`.

Comment: I have no clue "how it is working" the id is picked up in my subsequent function -- so totally bizarre to me

Comment: @H.Ferrence Very weird... By the way, your function is returning an undefined variable if your condition is met and `$post` is not used. You might want to fix that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this @jeroen. I will choose your answer so I can close this question out. Your solution will work fine. But the real answer to my problem was that the server hosting provider unilaterally shut down email forms on the site without ever informing me. They did so because they detected the form was being used as a proxy for sending out spam. Maybe so, but one would think the service provider would inform the customer and work with the customer to come up with a working solution. You get what you pay for, so they say.